# Let say I have two arrays with related data. How can I search through first array and return merged related data between array 1 and array 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have 2 arrays **users** and **userCity**. I want to ***map*** through **users array** and ***return*** updated **user object** with merged **city** data from **userCity** array based on related **userId**

I get the error:

```
    > *TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
    >     at user.map.u (eval at <anonymous> (:7:47),*
```

```js
const users = [
  { userId: 1, name: "Jim", age: 25 },
  { userId: 2, name: "Rens", age: 15 },
  { userId: 3, name: "Ed", age: 5 }
];

const userCity = [{ userId: 1, city: "TX" }, { userId: 3, city: "NY", age: 5 }];

const info = users.map(u => {
  return {
    ...u,
    city: userCity.find(uc => {
      return uc.userId === u.userId;
    }).city
  };
});

console.log(info);
```

Note: 
I read somewhere that higher-order functions are synchronous therefore I expect the map function to return the values and assign them to info variable.
So I expect the console.log output to be an array with merged user and city info based on userId

```
[{ userId: 1, name: "Jim", age: 25, city: "TX" },

{ userId: 3, name: "Ed", age: 5, city: "NY" }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating through `users`, you will want to iterate through `userCity`, since you only want to merge data into that array of objects (not the other way round).

With that in mind, when you iterate through `userCity`, you simply fetch the matching user from the `users` array by using `Array.prototype.find()`, using a predicate/callback that enforce a userID match:

```js
const users = [
  { userId: 1, name: "Jim", age: 25 },
  { userId: 2, name: "Rens", age: 15 },
  { userId: 3, name: "Ed", age: 5 }
];

const userCity = [{ userId: 1, city: "TX" }, { userId: 3, city: "NY", age: 5 }];

const info = userCity.map(c => {
  const user = users.find(u => u.userId = c.userId);
  return {...c, ...user};
});

console.log(info);
```

Comment: Exactly the results that I expected. But is it true that the array map method (and other higher-order functions e.g - the find method too inside the map) is synchronous?

Answer (score 2):

You need to guard yourself against city info not being found.

```js
const users = [{
    userId: 1,
    name: "Jim",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    name: "Rens",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    userId: 3,
    name: "Ed",
    age: 5
  }
];

const userCity = [{
  userId: 1,
  city: "TX"
}, {
  userId: 3,
  city: "NY",
  age: 5
}];

const info = users.map(u => {
  const foundObj = userCity.find(uc => uc.userId === u.userId);
  return foundObj ? {
    ...u,
    city: foundObj.city
  } : u;
});

console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

If rxjs and observables are an option, to provide some modern-ish stream style, you could go this way:

```
    const users = [
      { userId: 1, name: 'Jim', age: 25 },
      { userId: 2, name: 'Rens', age: 15 },
      { userId: 3, name: 'Ed', age: 5 }
    ];

    const userCity = [
      { userId: 1, city: 'TX' },
      { userId: 3, city: 'NY', age: 5 }
    ];

    const users$ = from ( users );
    const user_city$ = from ( userCity );

    users$.pipe (
      switchMap ( x => user_city$.pipe (
        filter ( y => x.userId === y.userId ),
        map ( y => ( { ...x, ...y } ) )
      ) ),
      scan ( ( acc, curr ) => acc.concat ( curr ), [] ),
      last ()
    ).subscribe ( x => console.log ( x ) );
```

This should trace out a single array with two merged objects. This sort of pattern is pretty de rigueur (and very useful) these days.

Note you're iterating through users as the top level, though I don't think it'd matter either way.